# Embedded mono runtime unable to print float from managed assembly

Tags: c#, .net, mono, game-engine

I'm working on a game engine with mono scripting and somehow I encountered a weird bug in which if I try to print a floating point number from a managed assembly, like follows

```cs
public class TestBindingClass
{
    public static void TestManagedMethod()
    {
        Debug.Log(1.0.ToString());
    }
}
```

The following exception is thrown

```
[2023-03-12 01:41:00.576] [info] Exception:   at System.Number.DoubleToNumber (System.Double value, System.Int32 precision, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number) [0x000b2] in <88b1e1b97d1b40bbab202712607ae110>:0 
  at System.Number.FormatSingle (System.Text.ValueStringBuilder& sb, System.Single value, System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] format, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x000d1] in <88b1e1b97d1b40bbab202712607ae110>:0 
  at System.Number.FormatSingle (System.Single value, System.String format, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x0001e] in <88b1e1b97d1b40bbab202712607ae110>:0 
  at System.Single.ToString (System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x00009] in <88b1e1b97d1b40bbab202712607ae110>:0 
  at Helium.TestBindingClass.TestManagedMethod () [0x0005a] in <c5e17dc214154c4c90efd1ec2220c247>:0
```

This is a snippet of the CMakeLists regarding mono

```
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:$ENV{MONO_DIR}/lib/pkgconfig")

target_include_directories(PROJECT_NAME PRIVATE
        $ENV{MONO_DIR}/include/mono-2.0)

message(STATUS "PKG_CONFIG_PATH: $ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}")
execute_process(COMMAND pkg-config --cflags mono-2 OUTPUT_VARIABLE MONO_CFLAGS)
execute_process(COMMAND pkg-config --libs mono-2 OUTPUT_VARIABLE MONO_LIBS)
# remove trailing whitespace
string(STRIP ${MONO_CFLAGS} MONO_CFLAGS)
string(STRIP ${MONO_LIBS} MONO_LIBS)
target_compile_options(PROJECT_NAME PRIVATE ${MONO_CFLAGS})
target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME PRIVATE ${MONO_LIBS})
message(STATUS "MONO_CFLAGS: ${MONO_CFLAGS}")
message(STATUS "MONO_LIBS: ${MONO_LIBS}")
```

I tried adding other mono libraries to link to the executable, but the same thing happened. I tried loading additional .NET assemblies at start up of the application via mono, but .NET standard library assemblies simply won't load.

Edit: am on mac os
Edit2: This exception happens with both floats and doubles.

Comment: This looks strange. `1.0` is a `double` and you are calling `Double.ToString()`, why is there `Single.ToString(IFormatProvider)` in the stack trace?

Comment: I'm not sure why. Whether I put 1.0 or 1.0f in the C# part of the source code, it's the same stack trace.